# Randomize user input every loop

Tags: python, loops, selenium

```
import random 
user = (str(random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999)) + str(input()))
import time
time.sleep(1)
print ("Please enter your password")
passw = str(input())
import random
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

NumberOfEntries = int(input("Please enter the amount of accs you would like: "))
counter = 1
for x in range(0, NumberOfEntries):
    print('Entry ', counter)
    counter = counter + 1      
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    email = browser.find_element_by_name("emailOrPhone")
    name = browser.find_element_by_name("fullName")
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
```

What Happens: The user puts in his username. The code then randomizes it by putting in random number (between 1 and 9999999999999999999). It then opens the web browser and finds the username element field and fills the randomized username inside.

Problem: I have a loop function where the user chooses how many accounts they want. If they choose a number greater than 2, the randomization only happens once. This means that 2 accounts are created with the same username. This is a problem

What I want: I wanted the randomization to happen every loop. So if a user puts in that he/she wants 5 accounts I want the randomization to happen 5 times.

Any help into this matter? I feel that the randomization bit should should be inside the FOR loop, but I don't know how to make it so.

Comment: just move it inside the For loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify second line to

```
user = input()
```

Then add this in your for-loop

```
random_user = str(random.randint(1, 9999999999999999999)) + user
```